# Como faço para alinhar uma <ul> verticalmente?

Tags: html, css

Estou tentando fazer um site e queria alinhar uma `<ul>` verticalmente.
O align items não funciona mas o justify content sim

```html
<main>
  <nav>
    <ul class="nav-list">
      <li class="nav-li"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li class="nav-li"><a class="nav-link" href="#">About us</a></li>
      <li class="nav-li"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Products</a></li>
      <li class="nav-li"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Shopping cart</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</main>
```

Comment: Cade seu CSS? Está usando algum framework? Vc tem que dar mais detalhes na sua pergunta amigo

Answer (score 0):

Olá, dado! Suponho que você esteja escrevendo um css 'puro'.

Aqui vai como fazer isso de maneira bem simples.

```
<style>
  ul.nav-list li.nav-li{
    display: block;
    float: left;

    width: 25%;
  }
</style>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E se quiser ir um pouco mais a fundo e já ir vendo sobre boas práticas. Aqui vai um [link](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/pt/articles/outside-in-ordering-css-properties-by-importance--cms-21685).

Answer (score 0):

Ou ainda:

```
 <style>
  li{
      display: inline;
  }
  </style>
```